# UNIX: using comm without creating temporary files

Tags: wget, stdin, uniq, comm

I wanted to use comm to compare 2 lists: one consists of randomly generated words:

```
cat /dev/urandom | head -n 10000 | strings | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | sort
```

the other one is an english dictionary:

```
wget -q0- <URL> | sort
```

(I can't really give away the URL)
I tried saving both lists to temporary files and then used 
    comm -12 file1 file2
and it worked, but now i want to do it without creating those temporary files. Is there a way?

Comment: Do you require POSIX shell or is a solution using Bash or Zsh constructs acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

Your code (with the [useless use of `cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) refactored) can be trivially rewritten to use a Bash [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
comm <(head -n 10000 </dev/urandom |
        strings | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | sort) <(wget -q0- <URL> | sort)
```

However, unless your goal is to expedite the heat death of the universe, your code looks massively inefficient. Perhaps you should explain what you are trying to accomplish? (Plus if you want to find the frequency of dictionary words in `/dev/urandom` output, I believe `strings` will be filtering out any really short words.)

Comment: I was revising for an exam and this was one of the exercices, it specifically mentioned using strings and the task mentioned that efficiency isn't really a problem. Anyways your solution worked ! thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Btw i found another solution, not using comm.

```
((head -n 10000 </dev/urandom | strings | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | sort | uniq) ; (wget -q0- <URL> | sort)) | sort | uniq -d
```

It's not very efficient, but it works (uniq -d only prints duplicated lines = lines in both files).